# By default use default value check box is checked in magento catalog inventory

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.9, soapserver

I tried this below code to add product to magento catalog inventory, but the check box is still in check, how can i uncheck " Use Default Values" check box in magento catalog inventory, any one please help me.

```
catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity inventory = new catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity();
inventory.qty = "0";
inventory.manage_stock =1;
inventory.use_default_website_stock = 0;
inventory.use_default_website_stockSpecified = false;
catalogProductCreateEntity productEntity = new catalogProductCreateEntity();
productEntity.stock_data=inventory;
var client = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();
    client.catalogProductUpdate(sessionId, productId, productEntity, storeView, "ID");
```

When i used the above code, i got out put in magento catalog inventory as below image
[image]